# Shared preferences null (getstring) error in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I am working on flutter project and I save data to shared preferences for later use.While calling shared preferences as

```
tempData=sharedPreferences.getString('tempData');
```

it shows type error as

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getString')
    at success_page
```

This error is showing in all pages where I call shared preferences. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

the first thing I always do is make an instance of the sharedPreference class

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
```

then I can use your methods

```
prefs.getBool(Constant().IS_TESTING);
```

Comment: but i have made the instance as a common in string constants file